# Spring Rest - Entity Graph Annotation Ignored and complete entity is fetched

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, jackson, spring-data-jpa

While developing REST services using Jersey I am finding that the entity graph annotation is being ignored and I get the complete object. Code below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONCERN")
@XmlRootElement
@EntityListeners(ConcernListener.class)
@NamedEntityGraph(name="concern.search", attributeNodes={
        @NamedAttributeNode("referenceId"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("name"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("mobileNumber"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("email"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("concernDetail"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "concernType", subgraph = "concernType")},
        subgraphs = @NamedSubgraph(name = "concernType", attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("descEn"),@NamedAttributeNode("descAr")})
    )
public class Concern {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "TXN_REPORT_CONCERN_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CONCERN_SEQ", sequenceName = "TXN_REPORT_CONCERN_SEQ", allocationSize = 0)
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "REFERENCE_ID", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String referenceId;
.......
```

Repository Code

```
public interface ReportConcernRepository extends CrudRepository<Concern, Long> {


    @EntityGraph(value = "concern.search", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Concern c")
    public List<Concern> readAll();
}
```

Jersey Rest Service

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("findAll")
    public List<Concern> getAllConcerns(){
        return reportConcernService.getAllConcerns();
    }
```

Output JSON

```
{"id":240,"referenceId":"671606","name":"TestM","mobileNumber":"777777","email":"1","concernDetail":"1","latlong":"100_100","address":"this is a test address","concertTypestr":null,"concernType":{"id":1,"descEn":"Concern Type","descAr":"Concern Type(AR)"},"statusType":{"id":1,"statusEn":"Open","statusAr":"Open (AR)"},"concernAttachment":{"id":240,"attachment":"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 ......
```

As can be seen the entire entity has been loaded rather than the attributes. What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

I am probably too late for the party, but I had similar problem. It seems natural to use Entity Graph for task you described, but unfortunately that will not work. And reason for that is Jackson which calls every getter in your entity during serialization, so at the end of the day it does not matter which attributes you included in your Entity Graph (and others are only lazy-loaded), because Jackson will get them anyway. I found only one simple solution: @JsonIgnore which is definitely not as flexible as Entity Graph. Plus not all JPA ORMs are ready for 100% Entity Graph support, see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9270